# How can i load another activity under tab - android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

i created one tab menu.when i click the tab it opens one activity under the tab that activity contains two buttons.when clicking the buttons it open the new activity it does not open a activity under that tab itself.how should i open a another activity under the same menu.please help friends.

i used this code to open a another activity when button was clicked

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(SongsActivity.this,FiveActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
                   } });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
     public void onClick(View v)
     {

         Intent obj=new Intent("com.layout.Contactregistration");
         startActivity(obj);
     } 
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood your question then You can use simple logic for your button click.

First you can change your layout on button click that you are trying to open in a new activity.for this you can use

`setContentView(R.layout.SecondLayout);`

again on button click and initialize your FiveActivity's resources and use them.

this saves your memory and comfusion of activities.

Comment: Wow great friend. Thank you very much... @new Project

Comment: i used this it opens under the same tab menu but i cant perform any action if click button it does not click able helo me @new Project

Comment: ok then you have to initialize button resource from findviewbyid and set clicklistener to it then try and say what happenes.